# Timer based redirect problem using window.location

Tags: javascript, redirect, timer, window.location

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        var theBar = createProgressBar(document.getElementById('progress-bar'));

        var value;
        function resetValue() {
            value = 0;
        }

        function showProgress() {
            value += 1;
            theBar.setValue(value);

            if (value < 100) {
                window.setTimeout(showProgress, 100);   
            }
            if (value = 100) {
                window.location = 'http://google.com';
            }   
        }
        window.onload=resetValue();showProgress();
</script>
```

I'm trying to redirect after the timer reaches 10 sec, but what I tried doesn`t seem to work (redirects instantly).

*not familiar with JS one bit, tried my best to mimick*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` means assignment

```
if (value == 100) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Any idea why this script doesn`t work with IE ? Works fine under Chrome, FF.

Comment: Should likely add the the result of the assignment expression is the assigned value: `(value = 100)` => `100`. So, `value = NaN` would have failed in a different way.